# Scala Streams, memoization and placeholder syntax

Tags: scala

I've been playing with Scala infinite Streams lately and I have noticed a strange behaviour. The idea is to prove that memoization works with Streams declared as a `val`.

Having following test suite:

```
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FunSuite}

class StreamsSuite extends FunSuite with Matchers {
  test("natural numbers stream, proving memoization") {
    var hitCounter = 0
    lazy val Naturals: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: Naturals.map { n =>
      hitCounter += 1
      n + 1
    }

    Naturals.take(3).toIndexedSeq should be(Seq(1, 2, 3))
    hitCounter should be(2)
    Naturals.take(3).toIndexedSeq
    hitCounter should be(2)
    Naturals.take(4).toIndexedSeq
    hitCounter should be(3)
  }
}
```

all works perfectly and as expected. However when I change a Stream definition to use underscore placeholder syntax in a following way:

```
lazy val Naturals: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: Naturals.map {
  hitCounter += 1
  _ + 1
}
```

all assertions about the Stream contents will still hold but `hitCounter` will get updated only once (and end up with value 1).

I think there is some kind of optimization happening is Scala side, kind of inlining, which suppresses any side-effects in the clojure body. Anyone would be able to explain?

Scala version 2.11.7

Answer (score 6):

The following two expressions are equivalent:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3).map { println("foo"); _ + 1 }
foo
res0: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)

scala> List(1, 2, 3).map({ println("foo"); _ + 1 })
foo
res1: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4)
```

The effect you're seeing is a little clearer in the second version. `map` is just a method that takes a function as an argument, and when you give it a block containing multiple expressions, it will evaluate the block immediately (and only once), just as it would any other expression.

The difference in the non-placeholder case is that any side effects after the arrow are happening inside the function. Take the following two definitions:

```
scala> val f1: Int => Int = { println("foo"); _ + 1 }
foo
f1: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> val f2: Int => Int = i => { println("foo"); i + 1 }
f2: Int => Int = <function1>
```

In the first, the brackets and their contents are a block that evaluates to a function, while in the second they're a block that is the result of the function.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! You inspired me to do a more thorough investigation. The one thing your explanation is missing is that placeholder expression returns a function as a result, hence it can be evaluated only once. I added it in my own answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder syntax used within curly braces is not a function but a code block which returns function as a **result**. The expression is evaluated once, hence any side-effects happen only once.

Comment: This isn't exactly accurate, since placeholder syntax doesn't require curly braces, and it's a little odd to say that an expression "returns" a result.

Comment: E.g. in `List(1).map(_ + 1)`, the `_ + 1` is an expression that defines a function using placeholder syntax. There are no curly braces, and `_ + 1` doesn't "return" a function—it evaluates to one.